# FileUpload Control not taking file name

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using FileUpload Control to upload images, I can select the image using that browse button, but when i try to preview that selected one, i am not getting the file name, its showing empty..

```
protected void btnImgUpload_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string strimage;
        string strfilename, strextn;
        if (fupImage.HasFile)
        {
```

In the above code,`fupImage.FileName` property should have to selected Image name, but it remains as empty string "" , so `fubImage.HasFile` condition is going false. I am not getting why the condition is going false, while the file is selected,? what is the problem here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is `fupImage`? Where is it defined?

Comment: Check for the View-state property of that file uploader Control, If View-state is false, then on post back you'll get empty value

Comment: @AlastairPitts fupImage is the name of FileUpload control object I think.

Comment: @Ates, S you are right fupImage is the FileUpload control..

Comment: I am using UpdatePanel, what i've to do to get the file name in file upload control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what i did to test it is
I create an Asp page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:FileUpload ID="fupImage" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnImageUpload" runat="server" onclick="btnImageUpload_Click" 
            Text="Upload" />

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and the code behind class is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication2
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


        protected void btnImageUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string strimage;
                string strfilename, strextn;
                if (fupImage.HasFile)
                {
                    //do something
                }
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and nothing goes wrong with that

I want to say to test it just create a very simple instance  and test it in complex environment may be there are some extra rules may prevents normal jobs! and sometimes it looks so unnoraml

Comment: This file upload is working fine in a separate application, but same this is not working into my main application,  if(fupImage.HasFile) condition is going false,still its showing FileUploader.FileName is empty only.. I don know why its not taking the file name.

Comment: ya i am using update panel. but its working fine in old forms with update panel. same code not working in mine.

Comment: fileupload soesnt work in async mode see this link http://www.asp.net/general/videos/how-do-i-file-uploads-with-an-ajax-style-interface

Comment: sorry, that site is blocked here :( what is that async mode while everything is working fine?

Answer (score 1):

Check for the View-state property of that file uploader Control, If View-state is false, then on post back you'll get empty value

Comment: EnableViewState property is by default true only. Already created image upload controls are working nicely in other forms and also the same code is working fine separately , the new one which i created only not working.

Comment: See what is the difference in your other forms and this form, Any page level view state settings, parent level view state settings etc. so you can sort out the problem areas properly